# Sigma Profile in COSMO - RS model

Tags: thermodynamics, quantum-chemistry, intermolecular-forces

As far as I understand, sigma profile in COSMO - RS is a probability distribution of screening charge density for certain molecular surface segment.

In COSMO - RS, molecular surface area is segmented into smaller surface segments and interactions between molecules are modelled via interaction of these segments.

However, I see that sigma profiles are made for whole molecules which doesn't make sense given their definition. Shouldn't sigma profile be made for certain molecular segment rather than whole molecule?

Comment: It is not a distribution of different interactions that can occur on a given segment, but the distribution of the interactions if you go through for the whole surface. So your first sentence causes the misunderstanding.

Comment: @Greg Yes, I found this definition in abstract of paper: Sigma-Profile Database for Using COSMO-Based Thermodynamic Methods, and it is wrong. I am reading Klamt now and there explanation is the same like what you said.

Comment: I do not think it is a definition. Also, there is a book on COSMO-RS by Klamt if you can find it in your library.

Comment: Yes, that one is wrong. I've found what you said in Klamt.

Comment: How did this go? Have you figured out the answer now over the last 5+ months? Please update us!

Comment: This post appears to be abandoned. It can be reopened if OP addresses questions/suggestions from the comments.